# How can i remove the progress bar in ios YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

i am using the youtube-ios-player-helper. I'm setting the playerVars parameter like this:

```
 let playerVars = [
    "controls" : 0,
    "playsinline" : 0,
    "autohide" : 2,
    "showinfo" : 0,
    "modestbranding" : 0
]
```

How can i remove the progress bar when the view goes fullscreen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a list of parameters including `autohide`. While it has been deprecated for HTML 5 players, it may help you with your problem.
Here is a link to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autohide).

If you set the parameter to `2`, the controls will hide automatically.

Comment: oh, I updated my playerVars, but it still doesn't work when the view goes fullscreen

Comment: Perhaps it is an aspect ratio problem. Have you tried setting `autohide` to `1`. The control bars only hide once a video is playing a few seconds. If the video is buffering, they reappear. Another question: Are you able to manually hide the controls by simply touching the video once.